# Comma delimited flat file source

Tags: sql, ssis

I have a text file that is split using commas

Simple enough to do in SSIS but i have the following row in my source flat file:

```
Desc,Curr,Desc,ID,Quantity  
05969A105   ,CU,BANCORP INC, THE DEL COMMON   ,1,2126
```

there is a comma in my Desc column and im not sure how i can ignore that comma

Comment: The answer is "rather painfully".  If you can generate the file with tabs delimiters rather than comma delimiters (assuming no fields have tabs), your life will be much easier.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, you can't do anything in SSIS (or any other app that I have ever used) to handle this, because it is simply bad data. If you need to persist with comma delimiters then you will need to get the data provider to use text-delimiters, e.g. double-quotes, to wrap the data. SSIS can be told what is the text delimiter and will strip these chars off the data automatically.

Of course this may raise the issue of 'but the text may need to contain a double-quote!', in which case you would be better off getting the delimiter changed to something else, such as a tab or pipe.